# How can I SEE every Pokemon in Pokedex to fill their names?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

I want to set Pokemon for Trade, but there's a lot of pokemon I didn't see so I can't choose them for trade. How can I fill my Pokedex with Pokemon? I've beaten all of the trainers in the game (I think so)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to see Pokémon to ask for them in a trade: when asked to select a Pokémon, simply scroll down to the bottom, select the "What Pokémon?" option, and enter the name manually.

That said, fighting all trainers *should* have shown you every version exclusive Pokémon.

Answer (score 1):

From [Bulbapedia](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Global_Trade_System#In_Generation_VI):

> Unlike in previous generations, the player may now ask for or seek Pokémon not yet registered in their Pokédex by selecting "What Pokémon?" at the end of the alphabetical options and typing out a Pokémon's name, though the gender of the Pokémon cannot be selected in this kind of search. This manual entry is not case-sensitive, and entering "Flabebe" will return results for Flabébé, but otherwise, if the player has not correctly typed an actual Pokémon's name in the language they're playing in, their search or deposit will fail.